# Smallest closed affine subspace containing nonnegative integrable functions

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

Given the space $H=\mathbb{L}^2(0,1)$, and the subspace $K$ of $H$ defined by:
$$K=\left\{f\in H: f\geq 0\right\},$$
I have read in some lecture notes that the smallest closed affine subspace of $H$ which contains $K$ is the linear span of $\{\cos(\langle h,. \rangle), \sin(\langle h,. \rangle): h\in H\}$, where $\langle .,. \rangle$ is the canonical scalar product in $H$. However, I am not sure what the exact explanation for this claim comes from? Any help or references to literature would be much appreciated.

Comment: You know $K$ contains $0$ and the span of $K$ is $H$.

Comment: @user251257 yes as $K$ contains $0$ the space I need is linear, but how does the linear span of $\{\cos(\langle h,. \rangle), \sin(\langle h,. \rangle): h\in H\}$ come into play?

Comment: They don't${}{}{}$

Comment: @user251257 ok so you are saying that the smallest closed affine subspace of $H$ containing $K$ is $H$ itself?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @user251257 ok thanks man